# Issue with jquery auto height divs vs mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently using a css grid system to develop websites for mobile devices.

I have an issue where I would have 3 - 4 feature areas/divs/boxes with a background colour and they appear to be uneven depending on the content in each so I got a jQuery script to equal the heights and does a great job.

```
$('#plans').each(function () { //CONTAINER DIV CLASS

        var highestBox = 0;
        $('.pad', this).each(function () { //EACH PANEL CLASS

            if ($(this).height() > highestBox)
                highestBox = $(this).height();
        });

        $('.pad', this).height(highestBox);


    });
```

My question/issue is when a user is on tablet, when they change from portrait to landscape the jQuery height measurement doesn't adjust without a full page refresh so they overlap and do all sorts of ugly things, Is there a better/different way to achieve equal height divs, can the code be adjusted, also take into account that this is backing on to a CMS so a user may change the amount of content in each box so I can't set a min-height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen the `window.resize` event

First wrap your code with a function

```
$(function () {
    function resizeHandler(){
        $('#plans').each(function () { //CONTAINER DIV CLASS

            var highestBox = 0;
            $('.pad', this).each(function () { //EACH PANEL CLASS

                if ($(this).height() > highestBox)
                    highestBox = $(this).height();
            });

            $('.pad', this).height(highestBox);


        });
    }

    resizeHandler(); // call for once when DOM is ready;
});
```

Then bind the resize event to this handler.

```
window.onresize = resizeHandler; // this is the binding
```

EDIT:
I think I could add that:
At first load you should call the `resizeHandler` function manually for once

I changed the code and checkout [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xuqib/25/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Hey, I thought I had this working, turns out not so much, could you please explain the correct way to "Then bind the resize event to this handler." Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) method to bind a handler to the *resize* JavaScript event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var highestBox  = 0,
      plansHeight = $('#plans').height();

  $('.pad', '#plans').each(function () { //EACH PANEL CLASS
    if (plansHeight > highestBox) highestBox = plansHeight;
  });

  $('.pad', '#plans').height(highestBox);
}).resize(); // Call the handler by default
```